# How to run multiple or single C++ .cpp files on terminal?

Tags: c++

Everything is running on codeblocks and I don't know how to do it on terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **1. How to run .cpp from Terminal**

### **1.1 Only “filename.cpp” file:**

`Make filename # creates “main” application
./main #Run application on terminal`

Or

`g++ -Wall -o outputname filename.cpp #”-Wall” activates all Warnings
 ./main #Run application on terminal`

### **1.2 Multiple .cpp files:**

#### **1.2.1 Selected .cpp files**

`g++ -Wall filename1.cpp filename2.cpp -o output
./output`

#### **1.2.2 All .cpp files**

`g++ -Wall *.cpp -o outputname
./outputname`